# Alternative definition of directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

In multiavariable calculus, we have the following definition for directional derivative: let $f$ be a function, $p$ be a point in the domain of $f$, $v$ be a vector of the same dimension as the domain of $f$, then the directional derivative of $f$ along $v$ at $p$ is defined as the following limit:

$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p + tv) - f(p)}{t}$

However, there is also an alternative definition which takes the form of a derivative evaluated at $0$:

$\left.\frac{d}{dt}(f(p + tv))\right|_{t = 0}$

I would like to know how one can prove that the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: By definition of the derivative, $\frac{d}{dt} \big|_{t=0} g(t) = \lim_{t\to0} \frac{g(t)-g(0)}{t}$. Isn’t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(t) = f(p+tv)$.

Your first definition is $$\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(p + tv) - f(p)}{t} = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{g(t) - g(0)}{t} = g'(0)$$ where the last step uses the definition of derivatives.

Your second definition is
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(p+tv) \big|_{t=0} = \frac{d}{dt} g(t) \big|_{t=0} = g'(t) \big|_{t=0} = g'(0)$$

so the two definitions are equivalent.

---

I kind of bet the thing that's confusing you is the second definition, which has a lot of weird notation. You should read it like:

1. $\frac{d}{dt} f(p+tv)$ is a new function that will still depend on $t$.
2. $\Big( \color{red}{\text{stuff}} \Big) \big|_{t=0}$ means first figure out what $\color{red}{\text{stuff}}$ is, then plug $t=0$ into that.